# nextjs with i18next and i18next-node-fs-backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I am working on a multilingual site , with `nextjs` for SSR and `i18next` for making multi-language mechanism.

Due to using next SSR, I could not use `i18next-xhr-backend` and I should use `i18next-node-fs-backend` but in this case I figure out this error for `fs` :

```sh
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/macbook/Desktop/project/node_modules/i18next-node-fs-backend/lib'
```

Is there any universal way to fetch `i18next` language json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After burning one day, I found how to do this. I use [i18next-fetch-backend](https://github.com/perrin4869/i18next-fetch-backend) (actually with little edit in this library, which I'll send a PR), in my `i18n.js` componenet, add `isomorphic-fetch` as regular fetch API in config obj.

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-fetch-backend'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'fa',
    backend: {
      /* translation file path */
      loadPath: '/static/i18n/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json',
      fetch
    },
    fallbackLng: 'fa',
    debug: true,
    /* can have multiple namespace, in case you want to divide a huge translation into smaller pieces and load them on demand */
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ','
    },
    react: {
      wait: true
    }
  })

export default i18n
```

for `i18next-fetch-backend` library I add below condition for default config , on line181 of `i18next-fetch-backend.cjs.js` file :

```
  fetch: typeof fetch === "function" ? fetch : (() => {}),
```

Comment: This is a solution. But it has the huge caveat that would slow down initial loading time of every SSR request as it has to wait for local file loading. So we need to consider carefully. Btw, I don't understand why next.js doesn't recognize fs module even in the server side.